# Looking for an standard way to post json data on full postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I wonder if I have any other method but a hidden field to post a JSON object to the server on full postback.

Imagine you have a form (with textboxes, checkboxes, etc) and you need to post a json string when the user post the form. This means, I would post all the form values + the json string but I can't come up with any solution but a hidden field.

Just wondering if there is any other option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden field is your only option. Unless you want to display the JSON to the user, in that case you can put it into a textarea or text input.

Answer (score 0):

I used this recently in my web app:

```
$('#submit').live('click',function(){ 

  var postData = {};
  $('#items tr').not(':first').each(function(index, value) {
   var keyPrefix = 'data[' + index + ']';
   postData[keyPrefix + '[index]'] = index;
   postData[keyPrefix + '[supp_short_code]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.supp_short_code').text();
   postData[keyPrefix + '[project_ref]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.project_ref').text();
   postData[keyPrefix + '[om_part_no]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.om_part_no').text();
   postData[keyPrefix + '[description]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.description').text();
   postData[keyPrefix + '[quantity_input]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity_input').val();
   postData[keyPrefix + '[cost_of_items]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_of_items').text();
   postData[keyPrefix + '[cost_total_td]'] = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cost_total_td').text();
  });

                $.ajax
                    ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "order.php",
  dataType: "json",
                    data: postData,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(order_id)
                        {
    alert("Order Saved");
    $('#assigned_id').html(order_id);
                        }
                    });
});
```

Give this a try in your application or post you html and i can form the json...